# Not able to fetch store values when a link is hit directly

Tags: plugins, google-analytics, url-routing, store, nuxt.js

Hitting a link from a website without visiting the Homepage is not setting the values in the store.

I have made axios calls in nuxtServerInit action and have set the data in mutations. I am able to access this data everywhere in the project now but if I load a particular page from the website then the data is not shown until refreshed.

Following is `store/index.js` file

```
/* eslint-disable */

import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      organisation: Object,
    },
    mutations: {
      setOrganisation(state, organisation){
        state.organisation = organisation
      },
    },
    actions: {
      nuxtServerInit({ commit }, context){
        axios.get(api-link-to-fetch-data-from-backend))
        .then(res => {
          commit("setOrganisation", res.data[0])
        })
        .catch(e => context.error(e));       
      }
    },
    getters: {
      getOrganisation(state){
        return state.organisation;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This data needs to be used in the navigation bar. So it is being fetched from the store in `layout/default.vue` in the `created method` like this,

```
created() {
    this.organisation = this.$store.getters.getOrganisation;
}
```

As nuxtServerInit is the first function that is called in the nuxt lifecycle why is the data not being stored when any link from the website is accessed directly?

Example here: 
[Post](https://telugu.factly.in/factcheck/%E0%B0%AA%E0%B1%8B%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%9F%E0%B1%8D-%E0%B0%B2%E0%B1%8B-%E0%B0%9A%E0%B1%86%E0%B0%AA%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%AA%E0%B0%BF%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%9F%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%9F%E0%B1%81%E0%B0%97%E0%B0%BE-%E0%B0%9C%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%9E%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%82-%E0%B0%B5%E0%B0%BF%E0%B0%B7%E0%B0%AF%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%B2%E0%B1%8B-%E0%B0%92%E0%B0%AC%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%BE-%E0%B0%85%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%AC%E0%B1%87%E0%B0%A6%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%95%E0%B0%B0%E0%B1%8D-%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%A6%E0%B1%81-%E0%B0%A4%E0%B0%B2-%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%BF%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%9A%E0%B1%81%E0%B0%95%E0%B1%81%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%9F%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%BF-%E0%B0%85%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%B2%E0%B1%87%E0%B0%A6%E0%B1%81.)

This information about the recent videos gets set after refreshing the page.